# Website Lock for Windows

Tags: windows-8, security

Is there a way/hack/software to lock a domain (not just the main page but the whole domain. e.g. Not just superuser.com but also superuser.com/questions/ask and everything else.) in Windows 8 with a password?

I already know editing the hosts file in drivers in windows folder but it neither gives option to use password not blocks the whole domain. I can't use software that block "bad websites" from minors as well as my purpose are not of certain category.

Clarification:
I am not talking about website I am hosting. I am talking about making certain websites inaccessible from my personal computer.

Comment: You want to password protect external websites? Why would you want that? This doesn't seem to be something you should be wanting.

Comment: Is this a website you are hosting and want a password for users to enter or block a website on the internet so people on your computer can't access it (like parental control)?

Comment: I want a specific domain to be inaccessible from my computer. I will edit my question.

Comment: Without using software on your PC then the next logical option is to install and configure a physical firewall box such as a SonicWall.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If possible I am looking for a "software only" method.

Comment: @user314361 did I get kicked in the head by a horse? I am pretty sure you said: `I can't use software`

Comment: Maybe this? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/family-safety-child-kid-protect-filter-sites-chat-faq

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry for lack of clarity. I meant I can't use Parental Protection softwares as they don't block e.g. youtubes or gmail.

Comment: @user31461 sure they can just configure them to do so ..

Comment: This question should have been asked in the very first comment: `What have you tried so far?`

Comment: What do you mean, “editing the hosts file [does not block] the whole domain”?

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is always going to be a hack because you are wanting to use Windows security incorrectly in this scenario. In general, you should use your login to provide credentials and then assign privileges based on those.

That being said, you could make a script to swap out the host file.

Create the following batch file and name it whatever you want.  I'm using the name "myrename.bat".

```
:: myrename.bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL

:: verify the first file exists
if not exist "%~1" ( echo ERROR: File not found "%~1" & goto endofscript )

:: verify the second file exists
if not exist "%~2" ( echo ERROR: File not found "%~2" & goto endofscript )

:: Create a guaranteed unique string for temporarily naming one file
set instance=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set instance=%instance%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
set instance=%instance%-%RANDOM%

:: rename the first file to a temporary name
ren "%~1" "%~nx1.%instance%"
:: rename the second file to the first file name
ren "%~2" "%~nx1"
:: rename teh first file to the second file name
ren "%~1.%instance%" "%~nx2"

:endofscript
```

Assuming these two files exist in this path:

- C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
- C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.other

Then you can run the command below and they will swap names:

```
myrename"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.other"
```

If either File A or File B are not found, that error is reported on screen and the process stops.

Because the host file is a system file it will cause UAC to popup a message asking if you want to allow this. To change that dialog into a password dialog follow this guide: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/77389-uac-require-password-administrator.html

> Open the start menu and go to the search box. Type in Local Security Policy, now hit enter. Once this program is open, navigate to Local Policies, then Security Options. Now scroll down until you see User Account Control in the name of the policies. Once you see them, find the two that say User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for.... Right click on them and click modify. Change the values to Prompt for Credentials. Exit the program.

I haven't tested this but it should work. Just put the command in a shortcut and it should toggle between the modes. A password is required to go back and fourth. This will also require a password for all administrator activities which is going to always be a requirement in this scenario if you don't want it to be easily bypassed.

**Update**

I've tested this and it does work. You must close any open applications and also add this to the end:

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

You can either make a seperate batch file or just tag it onto the end of the previous. Also, in your shortcut, make sure to go to the advanced button in the general tab and check `Run as Administrator`. Otherwise, it'll just throw access denied errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, I would recommend adding the site/s to your Router's Blacklist. As it is the easier way of stopping the user/s from accessing a site/s from other devices.

However, seeing that you want to access the site with a password it would be better to set Parental Controls within Windows that will do exactly what you are after.

Any site you put into the Blacklist will be blocked along with applications which could allow them to circumvent the lock-down. The other user/s would have to request access to the site which you can monitor.

Remember for Parental controls to work you must set the other user/s to Standard and either elevate your privileges to Administrator (not recommended always best to work as a Standard user and Administer from a Admin account) or create a separate Admin account.

Follow this link for the full tutorial from Microsoft:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/family-safety